# postgresql FUNCTION cannot detect the SELECT condition

Tags: sql, function, postgresql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION heckANDinsert(
    first VARCHAR(20), surname VARCHAR(20),
  No VARCHAR(30), nation VARCHAR(30), dob DATE
) RETURNS SETOF passenger AS $$
DECLARE 

name VARCHAR(20);
Sname VARCHAR(20);
Pass VARCHAR(30);
nation VARCHAR(30);
birthdate DATE;

BEGIN

SELECT first, same,passportNo, nationality,dob 
INTO fname,sname, PassportN, nation, birthdate 
FROM passenger
WHERE 
    firstname = $1 
    AND surname = $2 
    AND passportNo = $3 
    AND nationality = $4 
    AND dob = $5;

IF NOT FOUND THEN
    INSERT INTO passenger 
    SELECT MAX(passengerid)+1, $1,$2,$3,$4,$5 
    FROM passenger;
ELSE 
    RAISE EXCEPTION 'passenger record already exists.';
END IF; 

END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I called the function using

```
SELECT passenger_checkANDinsert( 
    'john', 'levis', 'v39949455', 'British', '1990-07-23'
);
```

the function will insert the right result into database if i change the first name to another. but it won't work if i change the surname and remain the first name same as database data. i guess there is something wrong within the select statement WHERE condition in the function, but i can't find any error for that..

Comment: sorry for the typing mistake.. firstname is a column in the database passenger table.

Comment: Why use a function instead of setting the passengerid to `SERIAL` and putting a unique constraint on the table?

Comment: Because the passengerid type was given INTEGER. i am not allow to change the data type for some reason.

Comment: @johnnily: you don't need to change the datatype. `serial` isn't a real datatype, it's just an alias for an integer which takes the default from a sequence. You can do that "manually" any time you want without the need to modify the datatype: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/e8548/1  Creating a unique value based on `max()` is a very bad idea. It will not work correctly and it will not scale at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
create or replace function passenger_checkandinsert(
    _firstname varchar(20), _surname varchar(20),
    _passportno varchar(30), _nationality varchar(30), _dob date
) returns setof passenger as $$

insert into passenger (
    passengerid, firstname, surname, passportNo, nationality, dob
)
select coalesce(max(passengerid)+1, 1), $1, $2, $3, $4, $5
from passenger
where not exists ( 
    select 1
    from passenger
    where
        firstname = $1
        and surname = $2
        and passportno = $3
        and nationality = $4
        and dob = $5
    )
returning *
;
$$ language sql;
```

- Using the name of columns in variables can be problematic. Just prepend an underline.
- Declare the columns you are inserting values into.
- Simple SQL will do all you need.
- Don't do `count` to check for the existence of a row as it will read the whole table. In instead use `exists` as it will stop reading in the first found row.
- Notice the coalesce to deal with the case of no rows yet.
- `returning *` will return the inserted row.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION passenger_checkANDinsert

(firstname VARCHAR(20),surname VARCHAR(20),

passportNo VARCHAR(30),nationality VARCHAR(30),dob DATE)

RETURNS SETOF passenger AS
$$

DECLARE 

_exists boolean;    

BEGIN

SELECT count(*)>0 INTO  _exists FROM passenger      
WHERE firstname = $1 AND surname = $2 AND passportNo = $3 AND nationality = $4 AND dob = $5;

IF NOT _exists THEN

    INSERT INTO passenger SELECT MAX(passengerid)+1, $1,$2,$3,$4,$5 FROM passenger;

    ELSE 

    RAISE EXCEPTION 'passenger record already exists.';

    END IF; 

END;

$$

   LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I think you are doing bad with `MAX(passengerid)+1`, why don't you use the `bigserial` data type ? If you are doing so just to not lose sequency of this field, you are not doing right.

Perhaps you need to add sequency to your field by:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE passengerid_seq;
ALTER TABLE passenger ALTER COLUMN passengerid SET DEFAULT NEXTVAL('passengerid_seq');
```

Comment: Because the type for the passengerid was given INTEGER..i can't change it.

Comment: @johnnily See how you can add sequency without modifying the data type of `passengerid` field